# Resizing image using file_column - loses image quality using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

i am using file_column to upload images in my scaffold. 
:

example of my code:

```
file_column :name, :magick => {
                              :versions => {"iphone" => "1024x768", "thumb" => "60x60"},
                              :attributes => { :size => 100, :quality => 100 } 
                            }
```

but it is not working very properly. if i upload images of 500 Kb - 1 Mb my results "iphone" image size is only 20-30 KB and the image is very much blurred. The images of high quality 3MB, also has the same problem. The image is of very poor quality in this case also.

Comment: What's the size in px of the uploaded pics?

Comment: The size in px of a `1.8 MB` jpg file is `1700x1200`. Another image of `1.7 MB` jpg file is `3264x2448px`. A small image of `1024x768 px` is of `293KB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what was the problem, the code worked when I changed `"iphone"` to `:iphone`(i.e. made the keys of versions hash from string to symbol). The working code is shown here:

```
file_column :name, :magick => {
                              :versions => {:iphone => "1024x768", :thumb => "60x60"},
                              :attributes => { :size => 100, :quality => 100 } 
                            }
```

In the previous case, it was resizing the image to `thumb` size first, and then resizing the `thumb` image to `1024X768` size, I guess (hence the loss in quality). Very weird though.